# Snowflake cte redefinition

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression

I have the following snowflake statement

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT * FROM table1
),

use_cte_1 AS (
   SELECT * FROM cte
),

cte AS (
  SELECT * FROM table2
),

use_cte_2 AS (
  SELECT * FROM cte
)


select * from use_cte_2;
```

As far as I know, snowflake still executes this without complaining. I'm just wondering if this is really allowed, and if I could trust the result?

Thanks!

I tried running on snowflake

Answer (score 0):

changing the code to have explicit values:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        $1 as a
    FROM values
        ('a')
), use_cte_1 AS (
    SELECT 
        *   
        ,'b' as b
    FROM cte
), cte AS (
    SELECT 
        $1 AS c
    FROM values
        ('c')
), use_cte_2 AS (
    SELECT 
        *
        ,'d' as d
    FROM cte
)
select * 
from use_cte_2;
```

we get:

[image]

which makes sense, I would have hoped this SQL generates an error as the symbol is redefined. But you can do this in a valid nested way, and that should remain silent..

Thus here the scoped `cte` is used:

```
WITH use_cte_1 AS (
    with cte AS (
        SELECT 
            $1 as a
        FROM values
            ('a')
    )
    SELECT 
        *   
        ,'b' as b
    FROM cte
), use_cte_2 AS (
    WITH cte as (
         SELECT 
            $1 as a
        FROM values
            ('c')
    )
    SELECT 
        *
        ,'d' as d
    FROM cte
)
select * 
from use_cte_2;
```

[image]

where-as if the first block is still at the top level, the sub-cte is not scoped:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        $1 as a
    FROM values
        ('a')
), use_cte_1 AS (
    
    SELECT 
        *   
        ,'b' as b
    FROM cte
), use_cte_2 AS (
    WITH cte as (
         SELECT 
            $1 as a
        FROM values
            ('c')
    )
    SELECT 
        *
        ,'d' as d
    FROM cte
)
select * 
from use_cte_2;
```

[image]